# Get all data except the value on the first case statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a simple select like this:

```
DECLARE @ReportType AS VARCHAR(255) = 'Machine'

 SELECT
   [WOCust3] AS [Machine]
  FROM MyTable WHERE
   (@ReportType IS NULL
             OR  [WOCust3] LIKE (CASE WHEN @ReportType = 'Slack'
             THEN '%Slack test%'
             ELSE '%'
             END
             ))
```

As you can see, I use the case to compare if the variable equals Slack then filter by that field; the problem is in the else clause. When the report type equals to another string it is throwing all results including Slack test results, and I want to get all except for slack test results, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-worked your `CASE` expression to better handle instances where the `@ReportType` is not `Slack`.

**SQL:**

```
DECLARE @ReportType AS VARCHAR(255) = 'Machine'

SELECT 
  a.Machine_Name
FROM 
  Machine_Data a 
WHERE 
  a.Machine_Name IN (
    CASE 
    WHEN @ReportType = 'Slack' AND a.Machine_Name LIKE '%Slack test%' THEN a.Machine_Name 
    WHEN ISNULL(@ReportType, 'N/A') <> 'Slack' AND a.Machine_Name NOT LIKE '%Slack test%' THEN a.Machine_Name
    END)
```

**Result with `Machine` or `NULL` as `ReportType`:**

```
| Machine_Name |
|--------------|
|    Machine 1 |
|    Machine 2 |
|        Other |
|         Test |
|          Dev |
```

**Result with `Slack` as `ReportType`:**

```
| Machine_Name |
|--------------|
|   Slack test |
```

**SQL Fiddle:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ca614/13

Answer (score 0):

You can break the `case` *expression* down into these pieces:

```
where case
   when @ReportType is NULL then 1
   when @ReportType = 'Slack' and WOCust3 like '%Slack test%' then 1
   when @ReportType <> 'Slack' and WOCust3 not like '%Slack test%' then 1
   else 0 end = 1;
```

Note that performance is likely to suffer with this sort of logic.

Suggested reading: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).